# How make animations work inside ScrollView in SwiftUI? Accordion style animation in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a accordion style view with animations using SwiftUI. But Animations are not working properly if I wrap it into a ScrollView.Below is the code that I am trying to work out.

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var isPressed = false
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                Group {
                    SampleView(index: 1)
                    SampleView(index: 2)
                    SampleView(index: 3)
                    SampleView(index: 4)
                }.border(Color.black).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }.border(Color.green)
        }
    }
}

struct SampleView: View {
    @State var index: Int
    @State var isPressed = false
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            HStack(alignment:.top) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("********************")
                    Text("This View = \(index)")
                    Text("********************")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Press") { self.isPressed.toggle() }
            }

            if isPressed {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("********************")
                    Text("-----> = \(index)")
                    Text("********************")
                }.transition(.slide).animation(.linear).border(Color.red)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And Below is the screenshot of problem I'm facing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make it animate, wrap `self.isPressed.toggle()` in a `withAnimation` closure.

```swift
Button("Press") { withAnimation { self.isPressed.toggle() } }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right but when I do my views are pushing upwards and my first row is going behind the visible area on the screen as you can see in the second screen shot I have attached